# How do you describe the sound a chair makes when someone is heavily rocking it on the floor?

Tags: word-choice

How do you describe the sound a normal chair makes when someone is heavily rocking it on the floor? Can I use the verb *thump*. For example:

> Stop making that chair **thump**!

For that matter, is it natural to say the following?

> Please don't **thump** the chair?

Comment: Is it a rocking chair, or just a normal chair? Thump or bump would seem about right if a normal chair.

Comment: It is a normal chair. Can I say "don't bump a chair"?

Comment: Or *Bang* - These are [Onomatopoeia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia) and so whichever sounds most like what you hear, is the one you should use.